# Can I use Camel and WMQ without JMS?

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-mq

I am currently learning Camel, and have a specific project in mind that requires a Websphere MQ back-end, but I can't use JMS components, since I need a lot of non-jms headers, like MQIIH.

I found the [camel-wmq](https://github.com/jbonofre/camel-wmq) project.
Is it the recommended solution ? Is it any good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested way of working with WMQ has always been through the JMS component since it enables you to painlessly switch to other providers if the need arises.

However, if you need to use some WMQ-specific function then my suggestion would be to extend the camel-wmq library - it contains only a subset of features supported by WMQ and does not support MQIIH headers that you need. Adding functionality to a component would probably involve more work than the [solution Souciance Eqdam Rashti suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40905852/4657798) but it would be a cleaner solution and more in line with Camel's philosophy. Also, you'd be giving back to the community and thus help make Camel a better tool for everyone :)

I would also suggest you go through the [IBM MQ discussions on the Camel's official user group mailing list](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=search_page&node=465427&query=IBM%20MQ&n=465427) and see if you can salvage anything.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use jms. WMQ has a client API. Just download the wmq client jars and put them in your project and use them together with your Camel routes. You will probably put the wmq client code in a processor class or something similar. Off course best to test to put a message on a queue manually via RFHUTIL or something similar as a client so you are sure the environment setup is correct.